# Mysql - why AND in where is not considered?

Tags: mysql

In the below query even position and category_id conditions are met there is no record 
retrieved.

```
SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs`
WHERE (interview_date >= '2012-05-03 17:54:41 +0530')
  AND (position like '%ROR%'
    AND category_id = '11'
    AND experience_id = '5' 
    AND interview_address like '%%')
ORDER BY interview_date asc
```

But for the same query when category_id and experience_id conditions are met I am getting the result.I am totally confused.

```
SELECT `jobs`.* FROM `jobs`
WHERE (interview_date >= '2012-05-03 17:55:07 +0530')
  AND (position like '%%'
    AND category_id = '11'
    AND experience_id = '5'
    AND interview_address like '%%')
ORDER BY interview_date asc
```

I have used AND condition but it returns result when only two conditions are satisfied.
Am I missing anything here?

Thank you folks.

Comment: See solution below: Why are you doing "like '%%'" ?

Comment: The search parameter position and interview_address is optional

Comment: I don't understand your problem and it's evident that I'm not the only one.  Please update your question to explicitly state what you're actually asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your other two conditions:

```
position like '%%'
```

and

```
interview_address like '%%'
```

are always true.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But if it is the case I should get the records for the first query.I have records with position 'ROR developer' and category_id = '11' and experience_id = '5'.Because last condition always returns true.